# Pass drop down list value to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple list view with list of tasks.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskText)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TillDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            <select id="TaskState">
                <option>Active</option>
                <option>Stoped</option>
                <option>Complete</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And class for Task:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TaskText { get; set; }
    public DateTime TillDate { get; set; }
    public TaskState State { get; set; }
}

public enum TaskState
{
    Active=1,
    Stoped,
    Complete
}
```

Now, I want to change Task state by selecting it from drop down list, but can't figure out how to conect it with model. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [ASP.NET MVC 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Enum) you can use the `EnumDropDownListFor()` helper

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.State)
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot!